# Azure AD error message when I try to connect my VM win 10 to my VM Server 2019 local domain

Tags: dns, operating-system, cross-domain

First time poster on this forum, I am a beginner.

I am trying to connect my windows 10 VM to the root domain I have created on my Windows server 2019 VM. When I entered in the name and password to an account with permission to enter the domain I got this error:

"This device is joined to Azure AD. To join an Active Directory domain, you must first go to settings and choose to disconnect your device from your work or school"

When I entered settings --> Accounts there is no option for me to disconnect Azure AD. When I enter "work access" I am able to sign in to Azure AD. why would I get the error that I am already connected if I need to connect?

When looking trough the accounts I could disconnect from the domain I am on currently. I am a student and the vm is connected to my student account. Should I disconnect from the student domain? When I press the "disconnect from the organization" I get a message that "I will no be able to sign in to this PC with your organizations account." This made me hesitant to click it. I am kinda affraid to be locked out of my WM. Is that possible? Both the windows 10 and Win server is a bridget VM if that makes a difference.

I have done some research but I could not find a comprehensive answer. This is quite advanced for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, after I posted and thought about it for a little while, I put on my big girl pants and decided to disconnect from my student domain. After all that made the most sense. I was able to connect to the root domain. The only this is that I am now connected with my personal account. Not sure how smart that is. But problem fixed :)